# Anti-aliasing when baking textures?

Tags: texture-baking, antialiasing

Is there a way  to bake textures with anti-aliasing, or is there another process to do that?

Comment: Okay so I've read that the workaround is to bake at a higher resolution and than down sample (resize) to the desired resolution.

Answer (score 2):

Adjusting the texture's interpolation from Linear to Cubic only improves pixel filtering for renders, **NOT** for baking. Currently, the **ONLY** solution to have anti-aliasing when baking textures is to **bake at a higher resolution** (ie. 4096 x 4096) and then **scale down** to your final size (ie. 2048 x 2048) using an image editor (or use a Blender add-on like [**TexTools**](https://github.com/franMarz/TexTools-Blender) which does this internally). See further details here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/262852/39431

Comment: Some addons like [TextTools](https://github.com/franMarz/TexTools-Blender) do offer anti-aliasing, though i bet it's using the same technique under the hood.

Comment: Yes, I believe TexTools is using the same method. Thanks for the link, that is definitely a very useful addon!

Answer (score 0):

Render (bake) using the smart or cubic options.
I imagine you'd need to float. Use .EXR for more definition for the antialiasing.
[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to improve the sampling for me at all.