# GPU Compute breaks after trying to bake normal map

Tags: texture-baking, gpu, normal-map

I was trying to bake textures for export to Unity and kept running into the same problem. **Everything seems to work fine until I try to bake a normal map** from generated shaders.

Settings are as follows (I get the same problem in CUDA):

[image]

As for render settings:

[image]

When I try to bake ***diffuse*** with **GPU Compute**, the output is as follows (*Correct*):

[image]

When I try to bake ***normals*** with GPU Compute, the output is as follows (*VERY Wrong*):

[image]

*Then*, **every map I try to bake** (diffuse, roughness, etc) **with GPU Compute after that** outputs either a blank image or fills the empty space just like in the normal map image above. ^^^

I can bake using CPU but it is **much** slower compared to my GPU.

Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: I would file a bug report directly with Blender, include the Blend file also.  In Blender Click `Help` -> `Report a Bug`

Comment: @RickT Thank you, I'll do just that. Also hoping someone here has a solution.

Also, brief update. If I close and re-open the file, it goes back to behaving as normal for other map types, but always breaks when baking normals.

Comment: @S4MR41 It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question directly.

Comment: Have you tried to reduce the number of samples for the normal map as a workaround? There is not much difference between 16 and 128 samples except that 128 samples take much longer to calculate. Have a look here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84897/do-samples-affect-normal-map-baking. (I don't know if it helps as the question is 6 years old and Cycles can bake textures with denoiser enabled these days.)

Comment: It looks like this question is about the same problem: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/303372/problem-baking-normal-maps-in-blender