# Problem baking normal maps in blender

Tags: texturing, normal-map

[image: The output normal map]

The image above is the normal map post-baking.
I've been following blender guru's anvil tutorial but can't seem to figure out why my the baked normal map lacks all details and comes out white like this, I've noticed the baking progress tracker get's to 25% or less then instantly skips to the end.

I made sure to have the low poly model as active, click on selected to active and select the images node in the shader Editor before Baking. Still nothing. Please help.

Comment: Hello please shareyour file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Seems as if this could be a bug... are you experiencing this when baking with GPU while baking with CPU (although slow) works? That is happening in this question here (cannot mark this one as duplicate since the other has no answer yet): [GPU Compute breaks after trying to bake normal map](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/303322/)

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I Switched to CPU mode on cycles and restarted my PC and the bake now works.

Comment: @Silver-will But it does work only in CPU mode, or GPU as well after restart? Still a bug then, it should work with GPU, too...